# Developing Risk Scores from Cox Regression model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, survival, model, cox-model

A simple question on the development of risk prediction models from Cox regressions.

Suppose, as an example, that I want to create a risk score for 1-year mortality in patients with cardiovascular disease.
Performing a Cox regression, I found 3 dichotomous variables (yes/no; lets call them variable1, variable2 and variable3 for simplicity), independently associated with the outcome. Each of these variables has a beta coefficient within the regression model.

In order to develop a scoring system to predict the risk of mortality at 1 year, I need to assign a score to the presence of each variable. Obviously, points within the score can (and should) be "weighted" according to the importance of the predictor on the outcome (e.g., variable 1 may give 1 point, while variable3 may give more points, if present).

Which approach should be used to establish how many point should be assigned to each variable in the Cox-Regression?
One approach (perhaps naive) would be to transform the beta-coefficients into scores, but I would like to know if there is a more "rigorous" method, and especially if there are reference papers to use as guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The question implies that statistical significance testing was used to select variable for the model.  This is a big mistake as discussed at length on this site and in my RMS course notes.  Once you successfully fit and check a pre-specified model, the points are just the regression coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Your "naive" method, combining the predictor values with their regression coefficients, is the way to go.

The individual Cox regression coefficients represent the change in log-hazard associated with each of your predictors. That's about as direct a measure of "the importance of the predictor on the outcome" as you can find, if your model is well-calibrated.

Calculating the linear predictor of the model based on all the predictors (sum of products of predictor values times coefficient values) then provides a combined estimate of log-hazard relative to baseline conditions. In your case with only 3 binary predictors and (apparently) no interactions, you only have 8 distinct "scores" to assign that way, so it's pretty simple.

In more complicated cases you can use a Cox model to produce a nomogram that can give a combined linear-predictor value graphically. Harrell has several examples of nomograms in his [class notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf), with Cox model nomograms specifically illustrated in Chapters 20 and 21. That document, his [textbook](https://hbiostat.org/rms/), and the references therein provide the documentation that you need.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is a good starting point. 
I still dont get how can I transform the beta-coefficients into a point system, what technique do I need to use and so on. I would give a read to the documents you linked.

Comment: @pankevedmo with only 8 covariate combinations and 1-year survival this is quite easy. With the R survival package and a `coxph` model, call `predict.coxph()` on the model with a `newdata` data frame that has all the same column names for predictors as you used for the model, and with `type="survival"`. The `newdata` should have a different row for each of the 8 binary covariate combinations and a value of 1 year for the time in each row; the value of your status variable doesn't matter. Output is 1-year survival probability for each combination. With `se.fit=TRUE` you get standard errors.